# Parsing drive as parameter to File() object in Windows gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, linux, windows, file

I am making a search engine for files in a directory, which takes a root directory 
as a parameter from the command line. I am parsing the parameter to a `File()` object, which is then recursively searched for files in all sub-directories and stores them in a tree. The problem is that, if I give an external hard drive (or any drive) as root parameter in Windows a `NullPointerException` is thrown. When I do the same on Linux the program works perfectly. Why is this happening and how can the problem be solved?

```
public static ArrayList<File> listf(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files){
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    try{
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for(File file: fList){
            Path path = file.toPath();
            // if the file is symbolic link don't add it to the list
            if(file.isFile() && Files.isSymbolicLink(path) == false){
                files.add(file);
            } else if(file.isDirectory()){
                listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
            }
        }
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("Given root is not existing directory");
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);

    }
    return files;
}
```

`directoryName` is the parameter from the command line.

`files` is an empty List of Files.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using!

Comment: I should have asked for the exception trace too, but I can see that according to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles\(\)), `fList` may be `null` if the directory path is bad. How are you passing in the `directoryName`? `"c:/"` or `"//c/"` would be required, I think, not just `"c:"`, for instance.

Comment: I am using "c:/". If i use "c:/Programs" ,for example, the program works fine as well. The problem occurs when I give the drive itself as a root directory

Comment: It may occurs in retrieving `System Volume Information` directory.  See [File.listFiles() returns null for 'System Volume Information' / unreadable dir](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4803836). You can check this by adding `System.out.println(directoryName)` at the catch clause.